# Incremental link of x64 assembly function

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, linker, 64-bit

I have an x64 assembly file in a c++ dll project.
For reasons beyond this scope I want the linker to generate an entry in the jump table for this function like any other c/c++ function in the project.
However when I call this function from my c++ code it jumps immediately to the assembly function instead of going through the jump table.
Any ideas?

Comment: Show your asm function, its C++ prototype and tell us where you're calling this function from (that same DLL or not).

Comment: Assembly code isn't relocatable by the compiler for reasons beyond the scope of this comment.  So don't have a jump table entry.  Writing a little helper function that just calls the assembly code ought to work.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, can you please post it as an answer so I can choose it? If you have links that explains the problem it will be nice :)

Comment: I'll pass.  This is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly code isn't relocatable by the compiler. So it doesn't have a jump table entry.